# Typescript: Remap values deep object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to pick properties from deep object? It seems `T[key]['default']` is not allowed in Mapped type?

```js
type MyModule = {
  title: {
    default: string
  },
  length: {
    default: number
  }
}

// expected type
type NewMyModule = {
  dataModel: string; // type of 'default' prop
  length: number; // type of 'default' prop
}


// error message: 'default' can't be used to index type 'T[key]'

type PickDefault<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key]['default']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why Typescript yells at you is that it doesn't know whether or not the key `default` exists on type `T[key]`. There are two approaches you could take to resolve this issue. The first one is to constraint the input type parameter `T` that Typescript would know what the type of `T[key]` is. See below.

```
type PickDefault<T extends Record<keyof any, { default: unknown }>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key]['default'];
}
```

Something else you could do is to use type inference. See below.

```
type PickDefault2<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends { default: infer D } ? D : never;
}
```

A caveat for the second approach is that if `default` is not found on `T[key]`, it will not raise any errors. Instead, it will just replace the type with `never`. Whereas the first approach will only allow appropriate types to pass.